# Can I persist any of the variables within a Python any() statement?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, any

Given the following if-statement:

```
if any(predicate(y) for y in range(0,len(myList))):
```

I am trying to keep the 'y' variable for follow-on actions, like so:

```
if any(predicate(y) for y in range(0,len(myList))):
    #DO STUFF WITH myList[y]
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'y' is not defined
```

Short of trying to replicate the any() functionality with several nested loops, I cannot think of a way to persist the 'y' variable and am unable to find anything closely related on this site.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you go about using slightly different logic if you want to persist the items:

```
 predRange = [x for x in range(0,len(myList)) if predicate(x)]
 if len(predRange) > 0:
   #hey look, it's already persisted in predRange!
```

Comment: Could this be improved to `if predRange:`?

Answer (score 4):

I'd write it this way:

```
for y, myItem in enumerate(myList):
    if predicate(y):
        #DO STUFF WITH myList[y]
        break
```